# ERROR in getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected TranslateFakeLoader to have an inner class declaration

Tags: angular, angular9, ngx-translate

I'm using angular v9 "@angular/core": "9.0.6",
after installing "@ngx-translate/core" and "@ngx-translate/http-loader",
I got this error "ERROR in getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected TranslateFakeLoader to have an inner class declaration" while running the app.

```
"@angular/core": "9.0.6"
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
```

Please any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use Angular in version 9+ and install @ngx-translate/core 13, @ngx-translate/http-loader 6.
This versions of ngx-translate are specific for angular 10, install ngx-translate/core 12 and ngx-translate/http-loader 5. Specific version of ngx for version of angular you have in table Installanion on https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Actually I forgot about that, I changed the version to the one's matched with Angular 9 and it works. Thank you, bro.

Answer (score 9):

Try changing target in the `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json` from `es5` to `es2015`